# Removing <br> with REReplace in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have some html line break tags in a text file that i would like to remove or replace with chr(10) using the coldfusion REReplace command.  I am trying

```
 <CFSET newtext = REreplace(text, "<BR>", chr(10), "ALL")>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what doesn't work? It's not replacing the `<br>`? Paste a small repro case that will make it easy for us to examine the problem.

Comment: As @rdubya says, you're not using a regex here, so you don't need to use a regex replace. And as Matt says... you need to post a proper repro case.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: You're using a case-sensitive operation, so I presume you have some `<br>` tags in their too, not just `<BR>` ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do a plain `<cfset newtext = replaceNoCase(text, '<br>', chr(10), 'ALL')>` ? Since it doesn't look like you are looking for something that needs a complex matcher, it will probably work better for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a regex here in case there are XHTML tags like `<br/>` or `<br />`:

```
<cfset newtext = REReplaceNoCase(text, "<br[^>]*>", chr(10), "all") />
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove only <br/> using regex? Thanks

Comment: Something like the following, maybe: `<cfset newtext = REReplaceNoCase(text, "<br[^>]*\/>", chr(10), "all") />`